# What should be the strategy for migrating existing .net remoting based code-base to WCF?

Tags: wcf

Assume that there exists a huge application code-base based on .Net Remoting as a communication technology. There exists many classes which are serializable (marshal by value) and marshalbyref (marshall by reference). How to migrate this classes to use new WCF, unified communication technology, with least or zero effort. At the same time ensuring the benefits of the new technology?

In one line:The goal is to migrate to new WCF technology with zero or least effort.

I hope, that I am able to put the problem very precisely.

**Note**: I felt that the SO entry '.Net Remoting to WCF Challenge' would be relevant. On looking it closely I figured out it to be a different. The question put forwared by me is very generic in nature and could benefit a wide audience.

Answer (score 1):

There is an article on msdn:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730857(VS.80).aspx which explains on how to migrate existing remoting based applications to wcf.